# How to Iterate from back to front in a diamond-shaped isometric map

Tags: multidimensional-array, iteration, pseudocode, isometric

Imagine a diamond-shaped isometric map, which is basically a 2D array with (x,y) coordinates and the top cell as the origin, as marked in the cells:

[image: Diamond]

I want to iterate through these cells from back to front, in the following order:

[image: iteration order]

What's the algorithm to loop in this way through an unknown same-sided map?

Expected output: [0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [0,2], [1,1], [2,0], [0,3], etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python *pseudocode*:

```
def iterate_cells(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1):
            yield (j, i-j)
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(n - i):
            yield(i+j, n-j-1)
```

output:

```
In [119]: list(iterate_cells(5))
Out[119]: 
[(0, 0),
 (0, 1),
 (1, 0),
 (0, 2),
 (1, 1),
 (2, 0),
 (0, 3),
 (1, 2),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 0),
 (0, 4),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 2),
 (3, 1),
 (4, 0),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 3),
 (3, 2),
 (4, 1),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 3),
 (4, 2),
 (3, 4),
 (4, 3),
 (4, 4)]
```

Comment: Ah, I just realized it's missing the bottom part of the cells, it only shows them up until (4,0). But thanks! I knew there was a simple way of doing this, my algorithm was full of ifs and whiles, so depressing :)

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you! [Here is the equivalent in Coffee-Script/JS](https://gist.github.com/293566e1eaeb278e1170#file-zigzagarray-coffee) should anyone need it for a canvas project etc.

Answer (score 0):

Considering map is contained in a matrix M(n,n):

```
// lateral loop above diagonal
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  // diagonal loop
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
    // the coords you are looking for are: row=(i-j), col=(i+j)
    int currentTileValue = M[i-j, i+j];
  }
}
// sub-diagonal lateral loop
for (int j=1; j<n; j++) {
  // diagonal loop
  for (int i=0; i<(n-j); i++) {
    // the coords you are looking for are: row=(j-i), col=(j+i)
    int currentTileValue = M[j-i, j+i];
  }
}
```

didn't test it in detail, but I think i think it works. Anyhow you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the submission!
Unfortunately the conditionals for the first "for" seem to be off. With these values the condition would pass, and the values would be out of bounds:

M(5,5)
i = 4
j = 2, since  i+j > 5